# Unexpected angle value

Tags: python, math, vector, geometry, physics

[image: Image portraying my problem]

I have a vector A with coordinates (-51.85,-2.38,-0.93). The normal vector at point A(lets call it Na) is (0,0,1). I want to calculate the angle between the position vector A and the normal vector Na. Intuitively, looking at the coordinates of A and the straight upward facing normal, the angle should be less than 90. However, i am getting a value more than 90. Can you explain, why is it so, where am i doing it wrong. Please have a look at the attached code.

```
import numpy as np
import math

point_vector = np.array([-51.85,-2.38,-0.93])
normalized_point_vector = point_vector / np.linalg.norm(point_vector)
normal = np.array([0,0,1])
# Normalize the normal vector
normalized_normal = normal / np.linalg.norm(normal)

# Calculate the angle of incidence using the dot product
dot_product = np.dot(normalized_point_vector, normalized_normal)
angle = np.arccos(dot_product)

if angle>math.pi / 2:
   print("angle is:",angle*(180/math.pi))
```

Comment: I have no clue where you get your intuition from... How could a vector pointing at least somewhat down and the vector pointing straight up have an angle less than 90 degress?

Comment: Please post your intuition so we can help debug it.

Comment: Try plotting those two vectors on a piece of paper first.  If you're expecting < 90 degrees, then you must have incorrect vectors.

Comment: The angle you show in the graph is not between `na` and `A` but between `na` and `-A`!

Comment: As @Julien said: if you want to visualize the angle between 2 vectors, you have to represent them from the same ORIGIN.

Comment: what exactly value do you get? Maybe you get `360-angle` instead of `angle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle between two vectors is taken with common origin, i.e.

[image]

Not

[image]

Your intuition is correct about the angle you drew, but that is not the angle you are calculating in your code. The correct angle between `(0, 0, 1)` and `(-51.85, -2.38, -0.93)` is `91.0265` degrees, exactly what your code gives.

Answer (score 1):

The angle should be more than 90°. Compare (0, 0, 1) with (-51.85, 0,0), that has an angle of exactly 90°. If we now have (-51.85, 0, -0.93) comparing the z value, then this -9.93 points in the opposite direction of the 1 in (0, 0, 1) which increases the angle from 90° to something bigger. Similar with the y value. Imagining both vectors in 3D helps.